# How to set click event for button in onsen ui?

Tags: onsen-ui

I use phonegap and onsen in my application.

How to set click event for button in onsen ui?

Thank you.

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ng-click directive. Because Onsen UI is internally based on AngularJS, learning AngularJS would help you greatly.

https://angularjs.org/

## page1.html

```
<ons-page ng-controller="yourController">
  <ons-button ng-click="foo()">Push Page 2</ons-button> 
</ons-page>
```

## app.js

```
var yourApp = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);

yourApp.controller("yourController", function($scope) {

    $scope.foo = function(){       
        alert("foo!");
    }

});
```